# How to add a dll into .net toolbox permanently?

Tags: .net, controls, toolbox

I am dropping the dll directly to .net toolbox to add controls( same as right click on .net toolbox and select choose items) but the problem with this is its only for current project. want to add it in .net toolbox permanently. can anybody tell me some simple way to doing it?

I found this tutorial from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286995%28VS.80%29.aspx

This seems very complex, I need a simpler method.

Comment: what platform do you use? Windows Forms, ASP.NET or WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your control class is public and that you've built the Release version.  File + Close Solution to be sure.  Right-click the toolbox, Choose Items.  Click the Browse button and navigate to bin\Release folder of the control project.  Select the DLL.

Comment: hello @Hans Passant i am trying to add MyDAL.dll from Release folder to another Applications ToolBox but is shows error! I am new to this Topic of adding DLL plz suggest me..!Can we do this for adding code snippet to ToolBox for reusable code? Help Appreciated!

Comment: This works, but it will not be permanent! when you open new project that control is not listed in toolbox.